# How do I make the Mixnode Crawler to crawl slower?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

We topped 20 million pages/hour and I truly appreciate the speed; however I'm afraid I may be putting too much pressure on target sites, is there any way we can decrease the speed at which websites are crawled?

Comment: The webpage says: "Mixnode runs blazingly fast while staying completely polite. It follows robots.txt directives and __limits requests per website and IP address__ to prevent undue stress on web servers." so maybe there isn't a problem?

Comment: Here is the important bit from the website: "There is a __minimum delay of 10 seconds between requests sent to the same website.__ If robots.txt directives of a website require a longer delay, Mixnode will follow the delay duration specified by the robots.txt directives."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to decrease the speed as the [documentation](https://www.mixnode.com/docs/crawling/limits) clearly states that :

> There is a **minimum delay of 10 seconds** between requests sent to the same website. If robots.txt directives of a website require a longer delay, Mixnode will follow the delay duration specified by the robots.txt directives.